# How to fix the error "There is a problem with Oracle ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number"?

Tags: python, oracle11g, cx-oracle

I have been working on this code about inserting values for the value Blob because I can't do it inside the oracle database by itself which brought me to write it in Python and that seems to be the only possible way. I have been looking at other solutions but after trying them I haven't seemed to find the solution for my program. What I'm doing is INSERTING. Hope it makes sense.

```
# importing module
import cx_Oracle


def convertToBinaryData(filename):
    # Convert digital data to binary format
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
        binaryData = file.read()
    return binaryData


def insertBLOB(r_id, r_name, r_email, r_address, r_description, r_hpno, r_whatsapp, r_peakhour, r_rating, r_cert):
    # Create a table in Oracle database
    try:

        con = cx_Oracle.connect('Hazim11/87097980@localhost')
        # Now execute the sqlquery
        cursor = con.cursor()
        cert_pic = convertToBinaryData(r_cert)
        print(con.version)

        sql_insert_blob_query = """INSERT INTO RESTAURANT (R_ID,R_NAME,R_EMAIL,R_ADDRESS,R_DESCRIPTION,R_HPNO,R_WHATSAPP,R_PEAKH,R_RATING,R_CERT) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"""

        insert_blob_tuple = (r_id, r_name, r_email, r_address, r_description,
                             r_hpno, r_whatsapp, r_peakhour, r_rating, cert_pic)

        cursor.execute(sql_insert_blob_query, insert_blob_tuple)

        con.commit()

        # Creating a table employee
        # cursor.execute("INSERT INTO RESTAURANT (R_ID, R_NAME, R_EMAIL, R_ADDRESS, R_DESCRIPTION, R_HPNO, R_WHATSAPP, R_PEAKH, R_RATING, R_CERT) VALUES ('R100', 'MasterGrill_0', 'MasterGrill0@gmail.com', '145, Jalan Desa Taman Desa, 58100, Kuala Lumpur', 'Clean and Friendly Staff', '030-1110 3333', '020-1110 3333', '8:00 PM', '8/10',", cert_pic)

        print("INSERT VALUES OF RESTAURANT SUCCESSFUL")

    except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as e:
        print("There is a problem with Oracle", e)

    # by writing finally if any error occurs
    # then also we can close the all database operation
    finally:
        if cursor:
            cursor.close()
        if con:
            con.close()


insertBLOB("R100", "MasterGrill_0", "MasterGrill0@gmail.com", "145, Jalan Desa Taman Desa, 58100, Kuala Lumpur", "Clean and Friendly Staff",
           "030-1110 3333", "020-1110 3333", "8:00 PM", "8/10", r"C:\Users\HP\Pictures\Dota 2 Wallpapers\Wallpaper PC.jpg")
```

Comment: Don't use the `mysql` tag for Oracle questions.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't realise that Oracle Questions and mysql were different but thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

cx-oracle doesn't use `%s` for placeholders. It uses either numbered or named placeholders. If the parameters are in a sequence, use numbers: `:1`, `:2`, etc.

```
sql_insert_blob_query = """
    INSERT INTO RESTAURANT (R_ID,R_NAME,R_EMAIL,R_ADDRESS,R_DESCRIPTION,R_HPNO,R_WHATSAPP,R_PEAKH,R_RATING,R_CERT) 
    VALUES (:1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6, :7, :8, :9)"""
```

If the parameters are in a dictionary, use names: `:key1`, `:key2`, etc.

`%s` is used by MySQL drivers.

Comment: Thank you ! For now I'm able to insert the data but it shows on the oracle database row "[datatype]", if I'm not mistaken I saw somewhere that it was a link that I could press to retrive the picture, would you mind explaining a way for me to get the picture from the row itself ?

Comment: I have no idea what that refers to. I don't use Oracle.